# How to create a composition from functions

Tags: javascript

I have 5 functions: func1(), func2(), func3(), func4(), func5(). I need to implement the compositionFunc() function, which can take any number of functions as arguments, and create a composition from them. The compositionFunc() function takes my 5 functions as arguments. The compositionFunc() function returns a function that takes its initial value as an argument. This nested function successively passing through an array of functions with each iteration returns the result of calling the accumulated value of the current function-argument. The result of one function can be passed as an argument to another function. How can i do this?

```js
const func1 = (arg1) => {
  return arg1;
};
const func2 = (arg2) => {
  return arg2;
};
const func3 = (arg3) => {
  return arg3;
};
const func4 = (arg4) => {
  return arg4;
};
const func5 = (arg5) => {
  return arg5;
};

const compositionFunc = () => {
  ...
};
```

Comment: Welcome! Please take the [tour], look around, and read the [help], esp. *[ask]*. Assignments aren't usually arbitrary; your instructor, tutorial, or course will have covered the necessary topics for you to do this. **Review your course materials, class notes, etc.,** and **give it a try**. *If* you run into a *specific* problem, research it, [search](/help/searching) [thoroughly](https://duckduckgo.com/?q=site:stackoverflow.com), and if you're still stuck post your code and a description of the problem. People will be glad to help. [More here](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/334822/).

Comment: Things you'll probably want to use: [A rest parameter](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Functions/rest_parameters) and either [a `for-of` loop](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Statements/for...of) or a [`for` loop](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Statements/for). Think about how you'd call the first function, how you'd store its result, and then how to use that result to call the next one. Good luck!

Comment: In that case just `for` or `forEach` loop can solve the problem with ease. `for` loop is simple and useful. If you want to find a neat solution for your problem, [`Promise.all`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Promise/all) can be one way. Promise is best solution for asynchronous functions but in the case, it's easy and neat code to understand for your logic.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

you can define a function like this

```js
const pipe = (...functions) => args => functions.reduce((res, f) => f(res), args)

const combine = (...functions) => args => functions.reduceRight((res, f) => f(res), args)

const plus1 = x => x + 1

const double = x => x * 2

const pipeFunction = pipe(plus1, double)
const combineFunction = combine(plus1, double)


console.log(combineFunction(1)) // (1 * 2) + 1 
console.log(pipeFunction(1)) // (1 + 1) * 2
```

Answer (score 0):

A simple [reduce](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/reduce) can accomplish that:

```
function pipe(input, ...func) {
    return func.reduce((a, f) => f(a), input);
}
```

You pass it an initial value + chain of functions.

**Example:**

```
function f1(val) {
    return val + 1;
}

function f2(val) {
    return val * 10;
}

console.log(pipe(2, f1, f2)); //=> 30
```